# R: Reading in data form tab-delimeted file with duplicated tabs

Tags: r

I need to read a pretty large tab-delimited text file into R (about two gigabytes). The issue is that the file contains plenty of duplicated tabs (two subsequent tabs without anything in between). They seem to cause trouble in that (some?) of them are interpreted as the end of the line.

Since the data is huge, I uploaded a tiny fraction to illustrate the problem, please see the code below.

```
count.fields(file = "http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1429271380882.txt", sep = "\t")
read.table(file = "http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1429271380882.txt", 
       header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

Thank's for your help.

Edit

Edit: The example does not perfectly illustrate the original problem. For the whole data, I should have a total of 6312 fields per row, but when I do `count.fields()` on it, rows are broken down in a 4571 - 1741 - 4571 - 1741 - ... pattern, so having an additional end of line after field number 4571.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many columns you should have?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I added it to the question

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are `\n` strings randomly scattered throughout the column names. If we look for the first 5 or so occurrences of `\n` in the file using `substr()` and `gregexpr()`, the results seem strange:

```
library(readr) # useful pkg to read files
df <- read_file("http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1429271380882.txt")

> substr(df, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][1]-10, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][1]+10)
[1] "1-024.Top \nAlleles\tCF"

> substr(df, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][2]-10, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][2]+10)
[1] "053.Theta\t\nCFF01-053."

> substr(df, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][3]-10, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][3]+10)
[1] "CFF01-072.\nTop Allele"

> substr(df, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][4]-10, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][4]+10)
[1] "CFF01-086.\nTheta\tCFF0"

> substr(df, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][5]-10, gregexpr("\n", df)[[1]][5]+10)
[1] "ype\tCFF01-\n303.Top Al"
```

So, the issue is apparently not two subsequent `\t`, but the randomly scattered line breaks. This obviously causes the `read.table` parser to break down.

But: if randomly scattered line breaks are the problem, let's remove them all and insert them at the correct position. The following code will correctly read the posted example data. You'd probably need to come up with a better regex for the `ID_REF` variable to automatically replace it with a `\n` before the ID string in case the ID string varies more than in the example data:

```
library(readr)

df <- read_file("http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1429271380882.txt")

df <- gsub("\n", "", df)
df <- gsub("abph1", "\nabph1", df)
df <- read_delim(df, delim = "\t")
```

Comment: Yes, I think the root of the problem are line breaks within rows.

Comment: @Dominik, I've re-edited my answer to provide a fully working solution. Let me know if it works for you and consider accepting it if solves your problem.

Comment: Thank's for helping, but the data are too big to fit into memory all at once. I finally ended up by using `scan` to read blocks of a couple of thousand of lines and manually dealing with the line breaks (only one per "row" in the original data, don't know why there are so many in the sample). Nevertheless, thank's for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Check you file for quote and comment characters.  The default behavior is to not count tabs or other delimiters that are inside of quotes (or after comments).  So the fact that you number of fields per line keeps alternating and the 2 values add to the correct number suggests that you have a quote character after field 4570 on each line.  So the first line reads the 1st 4570 records, sees the quote and reads the rest of that line and the first 4570 fields of the next line as a single field, then reads the remaining 1741 lines on the second row as individual fields, repeat with lines 3 and 4, etc.

The `count.fields` and `read.table` and related functions have arguments to set the quoting characters and the comment characters.  Changing these to empty strings will tell R to ignore quotes and comments, that is a quick way to test my theory.

Comment: I actually checked that, and it is not the case.

Comment: @Dominik, what is just after the 4570th tab?  Another option is that there is an extra newline inserted at that point and you really want to read 2 lines as one.  The `multi.line` argument to `scan` can help with this.

Comment: I now actually suspect that it is really a new line inserted. I tried this: `read.table(file = fpath, sep = "\t", head = TRUE, nrows = 2, quote = "", 
                 comment.char = "")` without success.

Comment: There is another point: When I read in the first line manually via Scan, the character after the 4570th tab will be just `""`, but I manually checked and there are not two tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not get to the root of the problem but I figured out you have duplicated rownames in the table. I loaded your data in R workspace like this.

```
to.load = readLines("http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3c/1429271380882.txt")
data = read.csv(text = to.load, sep = "\t",  nrows=length(to.load) - 1, row.names=NULL)
```